# Get the argument passed to mock_open and call a different function for mock

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking, patch

I'd like to use `mock_open` to mock the functionality of opening a file, however, I'd like to know the actual argument passed:

```py
# module.py

file_path = "path/to/file"
with open(file_path, "r") as f:
    contents = f.read()
```

```py
# test_module.py

from moto import mock_open
from unittest.mock import patch

def test_open():
    with patch("module.open", mock_open(
        with open(file_path) as f:
            contents = f.read()
        return contents
    ):
```

Now I know what you must be thinking, this is completely useless and stupid as it ruins the purpose of `mock_open`.

However, I actually want to mock a different function, namely, [smart_open](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/smart_open/releases) and instead of opening the file on S3, I have it in my local testing environment. Hence, I'd like to use the `file_path` passed to `smart_open`, and then use `open` to get the actual contents. I also cannot use open directly, since the `file_path` passed to `smart_open` has a prefix of `s3://` and I'd like to get rid of it.

In essence, this is how it *actually* looks:

```py
# module.py

from smart_open import open as smart_open

file_path = "s3://path/to/file"
with smart_open(file_path, "r") as f:
    contents = f.read()
```

```py
# test_module.py

from moto import mock_open
from unittest.mock import patch
from utils import preprocess_path

def test_open():
    with patch("module.smart_open", mock_open(
        # something to pass to mock_open that says to do the following

        # get rid of the s3:// in the beginning
        file_path = preprocess_path(file_path)

        # get the contents using open instead of smart_open
        with open(file_path) as f:
            contents = f.read()

        return contents
    ):
```

Is it possible to do some preprocessing and call a different function (in this case `open`) using the argument passed to `smart_open`?

Answer (score 1):

Do something like:

```
@mock.patch("blah.blah.boto3.Session")
def test_open(m_session):
    m_open = mock.mock_open()
    with patch("module.smart_open", m_open, create=True):
        do_writing_function()
        m_open.return_value.write.assert_called_once_with(expected_stuff)
```

Basically you patch out smart_open's `open` with the mock_open, then you can read what mock_open's write is called with. `call_args_list` should also work here.

I patched boto3.Session myself to avoid dealing with the session stuff in my module, but since `open` is mocked, you won't actually try to open anything from the given filepath in the test.

In my case, I also had my open()/writing in a separate function, which you might want to do as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, didn't work for me - I still get no call count for mocked smart_open fn, i.e.:
>       self.assertTrue(len(mock_smart_open.return_value.call_args_list) == 2)
E       AssertionError: False is not true